# Easy-to-install LaTeX editor for Windows 8 with forward and reverse search

Tags: editors, forward-inverse-search

This is not a duplicate of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

I have a very specific requirement, which is not covered by that big-list question.

I want 3 things from the Latex editor:

- (1) Works on Win 8 without problems
- (2) Easy to install (I want to install it on several machines, so I don't want to spend an hour configuring it)
- (3) Forward and reverse search, either using a built in viewer (preferred) or with an external viewer like Adobe or Sumatra.

Which editor would you recommend to satisfy these requirements?

Comment: Which TeX distribution will you be using on these W8 machines -- TeXLive or MikTeX? Please advise.

Comment: I prefer MikTeX, but I'm happy to use TeXLive if that helps.

Comment: I don't know how long you might spend tailoring a configuration, but [TexWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), which is distributed with both MikTeX and TeXLive, should be very simple to set up and get running. It'll certainly satisfy your criteria 2 and 3. It's known to work just fine under Win7, and I haven't heard serious complaints so far about its performance under Win8.

Comment: I'm afraid I think this is a dupe: there's nothing here that is not covered in the more general question. As others have said, TeXworks would be the easy choice: both MikTeX and TeX Live come with it on Windows, and you'll need one of those as a TeX system in any case.